# How can I prevent "Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable" in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I want a changing background on my website. I'm now on my second page and wanted to do a different background color. I copied the javascript from my first page (because it was working good) and just wanted to change the querySelectors. But then the red waves popped up. I cannot change the [red, green, blue]. Or I can but just don't know how. How can I change the const [red, green, blue] so it works like before?

Here is a picture from my VSCode:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3TBE.png)

So here you got the working background.

```js
const [red, green, blue] = [255, 255, 255];
const background1 = document.querySelector('.background1');
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const y = 1 + (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) / 250
  const [r, g, b] = [red / y, green / y, blue / y].map(Math.round)
  background1.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
});
```

```css
.background1 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 7000px;
}
```

```html
<p>scroll</p>
<div class="background1"></div>
```

Comment: use functions with parameters. That way you don't have to duplicate code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing something like this:

```
const scrollListener74903087 = ( color, selector, offset ) => {
    const [red, green, blue] = color;
    const background = document.querySelector(selector);

    if (! background){
        return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        const y = 1 + (window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset) / offset
        const [r, g, b] = [red/y, green/y, blue/y].map(Math.round)
        background.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`
    });
}

scrollListener74903087([255, 255, 255], '.background1', 250);
scrollListener74903087([0, 208, 255], '.background2', 500);
```

Comment: A different question. So the code is working well but my browser is screaming: 

Uncaught TypeError: background is null
    scrollListener74903087 /scripts/background.js:7
    scrollListener74903087 /scripts/background.js:4
    <anonymous> /scripts/background.js:11
41 background.js:7:5

What can I do about that?

Comment: you are probably adding the listeners before the DOM is ready. You should try to register them on document ready.

Comment: I really tried all now. Putting the script before my </body> tag and in my <head> element. Browser is still screaming

Comment: @weti I updated the code and it now has an extra check. If the querySelector does not retrieve an item, the event listener will no longer be called.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the keyword `var` instead of `const`.

```
var red, green, blue;

[red, green, blue] = [255, 255, 255];
// your first background codes

[...]

[red, green, blue] = [0, 208, 255];
// your second background codes
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer, @RemsCodes .